# Best performance aproach for get the last records sorted by date

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, date, debian

I have a table with more than 60 million records. This table has 510 columns. All columns are doubles.

I created a index for date field:

```
CREATE INDEX index_btree_date ON mytable USING BTREE (date);
```

The table looks like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| id | date                | fk_system | col1 | col2 | col-n |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 2020-08-05 15:00:00 | 1         | 1    | 2    | 3     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | 2020-08-05 15:00:00 | 2         | 1    | 2    | 3     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | 2020-08-05 15:01:00 | 1         | 1    | 2    | 3     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 4  | 2020-08-05 15:01:00 | 2         | 1    | 2    | 3     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 5  | 2020-08-05 15:02:00 | 1         | 1    | 2    | 3     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 6  | 2020-08-05 15:02:00 | 2         | 1    | 2    | 3     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 7  | 2020-08-05 15:03:00 | 1         | 1    | 2    | 3     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 8  | 2020-08-05 15:03:00 | 2         | 1    | 2    | 3     |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried to run this query:

```
SELECT t.id, t.date, t.fk_system, t.col1, t.col2, t.col3 
FROM mytable t 
WHERE t.fk_system = 106 
ORDER BY t.date DESC 
LIMIT 2880;
```

This query take more than **5 minutes to run**, very bad performance.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Note: `date` is a bad name for a column. It is a very bad name for a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT t.id, t.date, t.fk_system, t.col1, t.col2, t.col3
FROM mytable t
WHERE t.fk_system = 106
ORDER BY t.date DESC
LIMIT 2880;
```

You want an index on `(fk_system, date desc)`.  An index where `date` is first does not really help with this query.